# How to not trigger exception when trying to write to HKLM on standard user?

Tags: delphi, security, registry, uac

I am *attempting* to write a value to the HKLM registry using `TRegistry` component in Delphi.

Since I am running on Windows 2000 as a standard user (or XP as a standard user, or Windows Vista as a standard user, or Windows 7 with a standard user), I fully expect that I will not be able to write to the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` portion of the registry:

```
reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_WRITE);
try
   reg.Access := KEY_WRITE; //sure, set it again, why not
   reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
   if not reg.OpenKey('\Software\Microsoft\SQMClient', True) then
      Exit;

   reg.WriteString('MachineId', s);
finally
   reg.Free;
end;
```

Unfortunately, the `WriteString` throws an `ERegistryException`:

```
Failed to set data for 'MachineId`
```

This is fully expected, which is why I'm trying to avoid the exception. I do not see any `CanWriteString` or `TryWriteString` in `TRegistry`.

How can I *not* trigger an exception when trying to write to HKLM?

---

Self-evident notes:

- if the user actually is an administrator then the write should be able to succeed
- wrapping the call to `WriteString` in a try-except:

  ```
  reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_WRITE);
  try
    reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    if not reg.OpenKey('\Software\Microsoft\SQMClient', True) then
       Exit;

    try
       reg.WriteString('MachineId', s);
    except
       on E:ERegistryException do
          {nothing};
    end;
  finally
    reg.Free;
  end;
  ```

  doesn't prevent the exception from being thrown in the first place.

**Update**: From RTL source:

```
KEY_WRITE          = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE or
                        KEY_SET_VALUE or
                        KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY) and not
                        SYNCHRONIZE;
```

from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724878%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> ```
> KEY_WRITE (0x20006)
> ```
>
> Combines the STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE, KEY_SET_VALUE, and KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY access rights.

Comment: Why do you care if the exception is being thrown since, as you yourself point out, you can trap it and not let it propagate?

Comment: The exception should only appear when you're running in the debugger, and it shouldn't affect the flow of your program.

Comment: Well you could try checking to see you have permission, can't see why you are bothering though. We use the fail a good deal, trying to figure out what to check on each OS to know it will, is a lot of work with no ROI.

Comment: Are you setting `reg.Access` to 'KEY_WRITE'? `reg.OpenKey` would return false then.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Exceptions should be reserved for exceptional situations, throwing and catching exceptions is expensive, even a caught exception will stop the debugger (annoying me and other developers needlessly)

Comment: @SertacAkyuz i am setting `Access` through the constructor. i can set it *again* just after i construct it - it doesn't change anything though, the call to `OpenKey` still succeeds (mainly because the key already exists - it's setting the *value* that fails).

Comment: @Ian - I just missed it in the code, I didn't mean to set it twice :). I cannot duplicate this behavior on W7, OpenKey returns false unless I run with admin privileges, whether the key exists or not does not matter.

Comment: @sertac possibly due to different delphi versions

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Likely because i run [`asInvoker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) (which also disables file and registry virtualization), and your test app doesn't have that manifest entry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get `TRegistry` to behave the way you want. There are no `TryXXX` methods and there are not parameters that disable exceptions. You can be sure that this is so because the `TRegistry` methods do not provide any error or status codes.

You will have to write your own wrappers around the Win32 registry API.

As an aside, I agree with your opinion, expressed in the comments, that `TRegistry` is lacking in functionality here. We expect registry operations to fail, and so we should not have to catch exceptions to deal with that.

Comment: That's pretty much what i was resigned to. Hoping there was a function tucked away somewhere (like [`CreateRegKey`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Win.ComObj.CreateRegKey))

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: `TRegistry` in XE2 has new `LastError` and `LastErrorMsg` properties so OS error codes are now accessible to the caller, even when exceptions are raised.

Answer (score 1):

Use `KEY_SET_VALUE` instead of `KEY_WRITE` when opening the key, as `KEY_WRITE` includes other permissions in it.  The fact that `OpenKey()` succeeds means that your standard user account has some of those permissions, so the key is allowed to be opened, but the key does not know exactly what you are going to do with it until you do it, so it cannot actually validate all of the permissions up front in case you dont use them.  If you use just `KEY_SET_VALUE` instead (which is all you really need in your example), `OpenKey()` has a better chance of failing right away if your user account does not have any permissions to write data into the key.  When it comes to accessing securable resources, always request just the minimum permissions you actually need.

Comment: i think you actually have it backwards: [*"A mask that specifies the desired access rights to the key to be opened. The function fails if the security descriptor of the key does not permit the requested access for the calling process."*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724897(v=vs.85).aspx). The more rights you ask for the more you need. In any event, i tried just `KEY_SET_VALUE` and `OpenKey` returns **true**.

Comment: ["When you call the RegOpenKeyEx function, the system checks the requested access rights against the key's security descriptor. If the user does not have the correct access to the registry key, the open operation fails"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724878.aspx). Your user account must have write access to a key in order to open it with `KEY_SET_VALUE`, so I would suggest calling `RegSetValueEx()` directly so that you can access the error code to find out why the writing is failing (in XE2, you can use the new `TRegistry.LastError` property instead).

Comment: Bah! i've been looking at `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\SQMClient`, when i *should* have been looking at `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\SQMClient` ! (*looking, meaning "with my eyes", in regedit*)

Comment: Welcome to WOW64's Registry Redirector. If you want to access the non-Wow6432Node version, include the `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` flag in the `TRegistry.Access` property, but only if `IsWow64Process()` returns true.

Comment: @Remy In fact you don't need to call IsWow64Process() since the  KEY_WOW64_64KEY flag is just ignored on 32 bit OS.

Comment: i didn't need to access the "64-bit registry", i was just looking in RegEdit and seeing that i shouldn't have access to open a key and was confused.